# Can you compare sequences with information about their series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be a sequence of non-negative, non-increasing numbers such that 
$$A(x):=\sum_{n\leq x} a_n \leq \sum_{n\leq x} b_n := B(x)$$
for all $x$.

Can you conclude that $a_n \ll b_n$?

You need the non-negative condition because otherwise you could have $a_n$ going to negative infinity $b_n$ be some something that converges to a positive number.

You need the non-increasing condition because otherwise you can set $b_n=1$ and let $a_n$ be $0$ most places but then large in some places so that there is a subsequence of the $a_n$ that tends to infinity (i.e. $a_{10^n}=n$ but $a_n=0$ for $n$ not a power of $10$).

Are these the only conditions you need to conclude that $a_n\ll b_n$? If not, what other conditions do you need? Any solution or reference would be appreciated.

Comment: What does $\ll$ mean here?

Answer (score -1):

Take $a_n=b_n$, then you wont have $a_n<b_n$, so probably not $a_n<<b_n$ either

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/652445)

Comment: This is an answer as a>>b implies a>b under very definition